# Best way to store information permanently from an Artificial Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Im asking myself what may be the best way to store and access information/data fastly on a pc. Im asking this in terms of Artificial Intelligence (espacially: Artificial Neural Networks -> LSTMs, etc.) because I want to know how to store information from an Artificial Neural Network (ANN), which has a huge number of Neurons and so alot of synaptic weigths to hold. By saving the data from the neurons I want to reduce the usage of hardware resources because the ANN just exists in the RAM and I have the fear to overload my RAM/JavaVirtualMachine (My ANN is  written in JAVA). I know that I could simply save the weigths into a file and let it read when needed but is there a better way (like datastructs or anything?) to save the information.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce RAM usage you can also simulate ANN in your GPU(and to speed up). You should learn openCL and JNI but I think this is good idea. I want do that in my own ANN libralies.

Comment: Thnak you for your answer! Ill see what I can learn and use fom openCL and JNI